# How to update object margin in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, position, margin, coords

I'm developing an application for WP7.

In this application there are some pictures. When an user clicks on an image, the coords of the other images change. To do this, I use this code on any image:

```
 picture.Margin = new Thickness(268, 90, 120, 225);
```

The problem is that when I change the coords, the area where an image was before is still clickable, even if it's empty and the image is on a different place! (the event works on the image and also where the image was before, but I want It to only work on the new position)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `InvalidateArange()` and `InvalidateMeasure()` for the first.

I'm afraid that clickable area not only in old and new position - it's problem with incorrect margins, so check it one more time, please.

Also, how you handle click event on your picture (with `GestureSercive`, you placed it inside `Button` or just `OnMouseLeftButtonUp`?)

And the last - layout with such margins `268, 90, 120, 225` it's not a good practice. Try to understand how your elements relate to each other and design your layout better.

Comment: I handle click event using "MouseEnter" event, I also tried with "Tap" event, but It's the same.
Where should I use InvalidateArange() and InvalidateMeasure()?
I tried in this way:

picture.InvalidateMeasure()
picture.InvalidateArange();
picture.Margin = new Thickness(268, 90, 120, 225);

But it has no effect :\

Comment: You're right!
The problem was that margins were incorrect!
Thanks mate :)